# How would you go about adding two input values to a multidimensional array in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, input

Say I have the following array:

```js
    import {useState} from 'react';
    
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([
      {name: "Television", price: 1000},
      {name: "Cellphone", price: 800},
      {name: "Pen", price: 1}
    ])
```

and the following inputs and a button on another component:

```js
<input placeholder="Name" value={} onChange={} />
<input placeholder="Price" value={} onChange={} />
<button onClick={insert function here}>Save</button>
```

How does one grab the new value from both inputs and add them as a new array to the original products array so that the result would be:

```js
[
          {name: "Television", price: 1000},
          {name: "Cellphone", price: 800},
          {name: "Pen", price: 1},
          {name: "Chocolate", price: 5}
        ]
```

and not:

```js
[
          {name: "Television", price: 1000},
          {name: "Cellphone", price: 800},
          {name: "Pen", price: 1},
          {name: "Chocolate"},
          {price: 5},
        ]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hey Lucas, and welcome. It would be very helpful to post the function you're currently running to add the values to your array so we can help debug ;)

Comment: when you want to push the value to the product List , onClick of save ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a couple of ways, I'll highlight one here as an example and mention others below.

For input fields, you want to store the value in state, for a functional component, that would like this:

```js
export const MyComponent = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([
    {name: "Television", price: 1000},
    {name: "Cellphone", price: 800},
    {name: "Pen", price: 1}
  ]);
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);

  const addProduct = () => {
    setProducts([...products, {name, price}]);
  };

  return (
    <input placeholder="Name" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
    <input placeholder="Price" value={price} onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)} />
    <button onClick={addProduct}>Save</button>
  ); 
};
```

In this example, we're using state to control the input values [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).  You can also make this more dynamic with multiple inputs that are child components and you can add many at once. It is very extensible.

An alternative approach would be to store a `ref` to the inputs and grab the values when you click. In general you'd want react to control the inputs, but there are exceptions. You can read more about `ref` here: [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Additional Note on syntax: In the above example, we're using [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to add a value to the array.  This creates a new array and helps to keep in mind that the `products` array is immutable and changes to it won't be reflected in the component.

Comment: The issue with this approach is, when the user adds a name of the product for example `laptop` and hits save  . The products Array will have an entry with `{ name: 'laptop', price: 0 }` . So a validation must be in place so that the user should not be able to save unless both the name and price are filled .

Comment: @Shyam Yes, that's a great point. However, the question doesn't really address the needs around this functionality. As asked, this can handle the functionality requested.  The OP is free to add additional validation and checks as needed.  I intentionally left this answer simple in order to not make assumptions. For example, the button is called `Save`, so you could assume they are submitting a form and that there is additional functionality involved with that. For the purpose of the question, I did not make further assumptions about their app.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need two states for your inputs :

```
const [name,setName] = useState("");
const [price,setPrice] = useState(0);
```

now you have to connect your inputs to your states:

```
<input placeholder="what ever" value={name} onChange={(e)=>{setName(e.target.vaklue)}} />

<input placeholder="what ever" value={price} onChange={e=>{setPrice(e.target.value)}} />
```

and in button you have a submit function in onClick like this :

```
function handleSubmit(){
    setProduct([...products,{name,product}]);
}
```

.

```
<button onClick={handleSubmit}>Save</button>
```